# Streaming H.264 video via RTP with VLC

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, vlc, rtp, sdp

I'm streaming an H264 movie through vlc 2.0.5. I've created the SDP file from reading the SDP packet through wireshark, and I was able to play the stream in vlc 1.1 and 0.9 (when the streamer is still vlc 2.0.5), but not in vlc 2.0.5. Streamer and Client are on the same computer (though it doesn't really matter).

The SDP file:

```
v=0
o=- 15358239906933506048 15358239906933506048 IN IP4 190.40.15.10
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 190.40.15.10
t=0 0
m=video 5004 RTP/AVP 96
a=tool:vlc 2.0.5
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
a=charset:UTF-8
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAH6zZQLQ9sBEAAAMD6QAB1MCPGDGW,aOvjyyLA;
```

The vlc 2.0.5 client messages shows:

```
live555 error: no data received in 10s, aborting
```

after it says the sdp file was successfully opened.

What could be the problem? How could vlc not being able to play its own stream by the SDP it created?

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you,

Guy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what caused the problem, but 2.0.5 was the only version of VLC that didn't work.

Version 2.0.4 and earlier and 2.0.6 and later worked with the same configuration.
Probably regression issues.